# State of a switch

Tags: android, android-switch

I want to get the state of a switch in the onClick method of a button.
Actually I want to save the state of a switch using the save button using Shared Preferences. For this I require the state of the Switch in the onClick method for the save button.

Here is some code..
This is the onCheckedChanged method.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Notification is " + (isChecked ? "on" : "off"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       if(isChecked==true){

          scheduleNotification(getNotification(w.getMEAN()),time); 

       }
```

I want to get the value of the boolean isChecked in the onClick method of the save button..
They both are different methods outside onCreate. That is why I am facing problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just save it inside the event handler or call another method. For example:

```
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Notification is " + (isChecked ? "on" : "off"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       SharedPreferences prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences(
       "com.my.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

       prefs.edit().putBoolean("isChecked", isChecked).commit();




}
```